# How do I reach the "remote" web app using IP routing? (locally reaching another subnet with VPN to get to an app)

Tags: vpn, routing, pivoting

I have a PCAP basically stating two things:

1. An ARP request `who has 192.168.a.b? Tell 192.168.b.c`
   An ARP answer with the MAC address follows of course.

The following requests all access an web app, which seems to be .php based (I can judge from the .php endings):

2. from 192.168.x.x to 10.x.x.x (access web app)

The traffic from point 2 is purely HTTP TCP and I need to reach the 10.x.x.x network, since I want to reach the web app.

I am connected via a VPN tunnel and I could discover the 10.86.74.7 is somewhy and somehow reachable by nmap and shows 53 port open, so it's probably DNS.

I tried the following:

```
sudo ip route add 10.x.x.x 192.168.b.c
```

But this doesn't seem to reap any results... How do I further pivot and access the web app?

Comment: This is a weird collection of facts, details, and missing details. I can't make heads or tails of it. Ultimately, I'm not sure what this has to do with security. This is a pure networking problem, and you don't even describe the network. And you had an odd collection of tags...

Comment: @schroeder could you please accordingly migrate the question then? What exactly needs improvement as well?

Comment: Migrate where? This needs to be completely re-written before it can go anywhere.

Comment: "I'm connected to a network via VPN. The address I have on the VPN is X. How do I reach the server with IP Y? The network looks like Z." If you can't provide any of those details, no one can even guess what routing would be necessary.

Comment: "ip route add doesn't seem to reap any results" -- why would you think it would? Is 192.168.b.c a gateway? Do you know how to discover the gateway? This pcap file, were you given it or did you capture it? (you used a passive voice). Nothing here makes sense and there is no indication that you know what you need to know to accomplish your task. And we can't teach you networking.

Comment: I am 100% sure that the 10.x.x.x is the gateway. The solution was to do `sudo ip route add 10.x.x.x via 192.168.a.b.`